# iAd is shutting down. Should I remove the iAd framework from all my applications?

Tags: ios, iad

> You are receiving this email because you entered into the Developer Advertising Services Agreement (“Agreement”) to use iAd’s advertising network and related services. We would like to thank you for allowing Apple to serve ads on your mobile properties. As you may know, the iAd App Network and related advertising services will be discontinued on June 30, 2016. More details about the iAd App Network shutdown are here. Note: Any outstanding payments due from Apple will be made no later than September 30, 2016, and campaign reporting data will be available until December 31, 2016.
>   This email shall serve as written notice that Apple will exercise its option to terminate the Agreement, effective June 30, 2016, 11:59 pm PDT. Nothing contained in, or omitted from, this notice shall be deemed a waiver of any of Apple’s rights, remedies or defenses, all of which are expressly reserved.
>   Regards,
>   The App Store Team

I would like to know the next best alternative to iAd network. Easy for integration and setup. Also, should I remove the iAd framework from my other apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iAd framework will be deprecated. You don't have to remove your iAd implementations just yet, but you will have to eventually.

Apple has given alot of information on what is going to happen: [About the iAd App Network Shutdown](https://developer.apple.com/support/iad/)

> **Apps that are not updated will experience the following adverse
>   conditions:**
>
> - No ads will be returned in your app.
> - A deprecation warning will appear in Xcode.
> - If your app implements ADBannerView and the ADBannerViewDelegate, the bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: delegate method, it will
>     be called with the ADError enum.
> - If your app implements ADInterstitialAd and the ADInterstitialAdDelegate, the interstitialAd:didFailWithError:
>     delegate method will be called with an ADError enum.
> - If your app implements the iAdAdditions category on UIViewController, setting the ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy will
>     have no effect and calling requestInterstitialAdPresentation: or
>     canDisplayBannerAds: will always return NO.
> - If your app implements the iAdPreroll category on AVPlayerViewController or the iAdPreroll category on
>     MPMoviePlayerController, calling playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler:
>     will return an ADError enum.
> - When your ADBannerView delegate receives this error, your app should look for other ads (from other ad-networks).
> - Apps that implement the iAdAdditions category on UIViewController and use automatic presentation, should not notice any impact. Apps
>     that manually manage the ADBannerView may see a blank space.
> - If you have implemented a mediation layer, contact the mediation provider to understand impact to your app.
> - ADClient APIs (requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock and addClientToSegments) will continue to work.

---

Apple also suggests removing the iAd framework on your applications next regularly scheduled update. So, submitting an update just to remove the iAd framework isn't necessary: [iAd for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/iad/)

> On your next regular app update or submission, you should remove the
>   deprecated iAd framework and connection.