# Implement iAd in Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I want to implement iAd to my Swift app with this code:

```
bannerView = ADBannerView(adType: .banner)
bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
bannerView.delegate = self
bannerView.isHidden = true
view.addSubview(bannerView)

let viewsDictionary = ["bannerView": bannerView]
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[bannerView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[bannerView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
```

but in the `view.addContraints` lines is this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : ADBannerView?]' to expected
>   argument type '[String : AnyObject]

I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: iAd is over. Apple doesn't support it any more.

Comment: iAd is being discontinued: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37337262/2108547

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `bannerView` variable is an optional, while your dictionary is expecting non-optionals (`AnyObject` not `AnyObject?`). You need to unwrap the optional:

```
let viewsDictionary = ["bannerView":bannerView!]
```

However, as others noted in the comments, the iAd network is shutting down from the end of June 2016 so no advertisements will be delivered to your app after this date. You may want to investigate alternate advertising frameworks.