# Swift: Application has iAd Configuration error

Tags: ios, swift, iad

[image]

But in the simulator and on the device it gives an error

```
UserInfo={ADInternalErrorCode=4, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Application has iAd Network configuration error, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain}
```

Comment: [iAd has shutdown](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37337262/2108547)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iAd was shut down on June 30th. You'll have to use something else such as AdMob.

Comment: Oh... Very nice! :(