# Sprite Kit Create an iAdBanner

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, iad

I want to create an iAdBanner in my SpriteKit game, but i don't know how it works. Could you help me? I haven't written any code yet, so I think I don't need to post my code. Thank you!!

Comment: iAd was discontinued by Apple on the 30th of June. You should use a different ad framework.

Comment: The iAd network has been discontinued: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37347959/2108547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iAd has been discontinued, you will have to choose another ad provider.

From Apple's [site](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a):

> The iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016. Although we are no longer accepting new apps into the network, advertising campaigns may continue to run and you can still earn advertising revenue until June 30.