# Block not getting called from requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, attributes, iad

I'm desperate. I'm trying to use iAd's requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock, and it's not calling anything inside my completion handler (I'm using breakpoints in XCode and logs. Any suggestions?

```
    [[ADClient sharedClient] requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock:^void (NSDictionary* attributionDetails, NSError* error)
 {
     if (error == nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"Attributes found");
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Request search ads attributes failed with error: %@", error.description);
     }
 }];
```

Comment: iAd? From https://developer.apple.com/support/iad/ - *"As of December 31, 2016, the iAd App Network is no longer available."*

Comment: @Pang, I do realize that iAd is now deprecated, but it mentions in the last line of that page: "ADClient APIs (requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock and addClientToSegments) will continue to work."

Comment: Well, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/37337262 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/38351562 and others in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iad

Comment: @Pang, I figured out the problem and it was not due to iAd being deprecated. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out the problem. My code was calling `ADClient` elsewhere (`determineAppInstallationAttributionWithCompletionHandler`) and for some reason it was blocking my `requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock` completion handler from executing. After I commented out the code, everything worked fine. Still not exactly sure why it works, but it does!

Comment: On the other hand, since [iAd is already shut down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAd), one could expect that the app would not show any ads and you will not receive any revenue at all.