# Why isn't iAd working?

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I have tried everything to try to get iAd to work in my app but nothing is showing up. I am trying to do it my putting in the line `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` under `viewDidLoad` but nothing is working. I can't get anything to show up. I have iAd imported and added to my app. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The iAd network has been discontinued: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37347959/2108547

Comment: I didn't use the proper link when closing, here is the right one with more explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37347959/2227743

Answer (score 5):

This service is no longer available. Check this link. https://developer.apple.com/iad/

Comment: Apple has created a lot of confusion with this. From what I understand the iAd App Network is different from iAd. So I should still be able to advertise in my app. If I am wrong, what other ways could I monetize my app?

Comment: @HenryP. https://www.google.com/admob/

Comment: What I understand from 
**"Developers will still be able to earn revenue from advertising from their own direct sales or by using other third party monetization services"** is that iAd neither. Basically because otherwise it would say something about developers or apps already using it, but talks about apps revenue only and not ads. Also offers you to start using third party services so is quite clear. Hope that helps.

Comment: Then if you check a bit below says: **"Revenue and campaign performance reports will be available on iAd Workbench until December 31, 2016."** so you're able to see the data related to your apps till that date but only to view and not work on your settings and stuff. Hope all this helps ;)

Comment: @HenryP. The iAd network has been discontinued: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37347959/2108547

Answer (score 0):

As of December 31, 2016, the iAd App Network is no longer available.

Have a look at [About the iAd App Network Shutdown](https://developer.apple.com/support/iad/)

---

`canDisplayBannerAds` will always return `NO`,

Effects of iAd Shutdown

> > If your app implements the iAdAdditions category on UIViewController, setting the ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy will have no effect and calling requestInterstitialAdPresentation: or canDisplayBannerAds: will always return NO.