# iAd banner blank

Tags: swift, iad

I'm trying to use simple iAd banner, but while checking in Simulator, I can see blank banner.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.saveJson()
    textField.delegate = self

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    self.bannerAd?.delegate = self
    self.bannerAd?.hidden = true
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.bannerAd?.hidden = false
}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    self.bannerAd?.hidden = false
}
```

Note: I also added iAd.framework into Build phases.

As you can see, iAd at the bottom is not displayed any content...

[image]

Comment: iAd has been discontinued by Apple. You will have to choose another provider.

Comment: The iAd network has been discontinued: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37347959/2108547

Comment: @DanielStorm Your linked page is much better than mine, I'll use it for such duplicates in the future - thanks.