# iAd does not show the "You're Connected" banner

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I've used iAd in my project. But my `bannerView` is not showing anything The `bannerView` is just showing a white background.

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class ParentTransfersViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: ADBannerView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        bannerView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you implemented func bannerView(_ banner: ADBannerView!,
didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) ?

Comment: @RomanPodymov yes

Comment: The iAd network has been discontinued: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37347959/2108547