# Cannot perform selector with function as param

Tags: swift, runtime, selector, iad

I have one small quest for you guys.
I want perform selector which contain function as param. But always getting runtime error.

This method is from iAd framework. And this is what I m trying to do:

```
 let sel = Selector("requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock:")
 if obj.responds(to: sel) { 
    obj.perform(sel, with: funcAsVar)
 }
```

where `funcAsVar` is a function as variable.
Help please, guys

runtime error is: `libswiftCore.dylib-[_SwiftValue dealloc]:`

Comment: What's the runtime error?

Comment: I don't think Swift functions get automatically bridged to Objective C blocks. Have you tried a Swift block that calls the function?

Comment: Actually you might be able to use `@convention(block)` on the parameter you pass to the `perform` method.

Comment: The iAd network has been discontinued: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37347959/2108547

Comment: Thank you, @DaveWeston! It helped for me. How I can mark it as `resolved`?

Comment: I'll add my comment as an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `@convention(block)` on the parameter you pass to the `perform` method. Like this:

```
let sel = Selector("requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock:")
 if obj.responds(to: sel) { 
    obj.perform(sel, with: @convention(block) funcAsVar)
 }
```