# Is there any costs for adMob usage from Google?

Tags: admob

Is there any costs for adMob usage from Google?

Comment: The iAd network has been discontinued: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37347959/2108547

Comment: @Cœur I think you removed 1st question from owner post. Need a rollback ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan multiple questions is not allowed, so you may rollback but then we should close as "too broad". And iAd doesn't exist anymore, so any question on it should be closed as "off topic".

Answer (score 0):

- https://developer.apple.com/support/iad/
- Your Second Question :

  Does it cost money to have/use Admob?

  **Yes** and **no**.

  No because you don’t pay anything directly to AdMob for having/using the account.

  Yes because when you monetise on ads, AdMob like any other ad network will take its cut from what advertisers pay to you.